# Function failing with closed workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that sums up numbers in a range based on the color of the font as shown below.

```
    Public Function SumByColor(pRange1 As Range, pRange2 As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colorSumTot As Double
    colorSumTot = 0

    For Each rng In pRange1
        If rng.Font.Color = pRange2.Font.Color Then
            colorSumTot = colorSumTot + rng.Value
        End If
    Next
    SumByColor = colorSumTot

    End Function
```

This works great inside the `Excel` workbook I where I made it. I can select ranges in the worksheet or other worksheets inside the same workbook.

However, if I reference another workbook it will work properly as long as the workbook is open. Once I close the workbook the cells with my function references the other workbook gives me the `#VALUE!` error. If I open the reference workbook again, the numbers come back.

I thought I should point out that excel functions work fine even when the referenced workbook is closed. (e.g. `SUM()`, `AVERAGE()`, etc.)

Why can't I close the workbook?

Thanks.

Comment: UDFs do not work on closed workbooks (similar to INDIRECT, OFFSET, etc). Rewrite the code to open the closed workbook, collect the information and close the workbook. If you plan to use this in many places, probably better to write a Sub procedure that opens the workbook once, updates all of the functions and then closes the workbook once.

Comment: Default requirement of `Application.Volatile` is: `The function will be recalculated when any cell in any workbook **in the application window** changes value` (reference link below). So the workbook has to be open for this to work. You might have to port the data over (could use formula's to do that) and then point to that range. **Reference**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel

Comment: Or put it in the personworkbook or create an .xlam file and create and addon.

Comment: Thank you for your help.